# Deprecated OpenGL functions

Tags: opengl

I am currently learning OpenGL via the 5th Superbible. It teaches you the core profile. But I am really confused.

I know that khronos removed the fixed function pipeline in 3.3 and declared some functions as deprecated. But the Superbible now just replaces those deprecated functions with their own functions.

Why should khronos remove something like glRotate or the matrixstack just so that I have to use 3rd party libraries (or my own) instead of the official ones?

Maybe the superbible is flawed?

Comment: Most of your questions are answered here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/509060-learning-strict-opengl3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

glRotate() etc was removed because internally openGL deals with the matrices so it is a cleaner design to just have you supply the matrices directly.

Almost all openGL apps of any complexity are going to be doing a bunch of other matrix stuff anyway and will have their own matrix classes it's easier for openGL to just take the result rather than insist on creating them from a bunch of rotate/translate/scale calls.

They could have supplied their own matrix classes - but there are a lot of 3rd party libs you can use. One of openGL's policies (failings) is that it does rely on 3rd party libs to do anything outside the actual graphics. So beginner programs are a tricky mix of GLUT, GLEW, SDL, etc to get anything on the screen - while  DirectX has everything out of the box.

Comment: "matrix classes" – no, they couldn't because that would limit the OpenGL API to the language those class libraries have been developed for. OpenGL is language neutral, only defining that procedure entry points should follow the C calling convention of the host system.

Comment: DirectX is a collection of libraries (including Direct3D for graphics), while OpenGL is a single library. The policy is a pitfall in a way that it requires more boilerplate code/setup to get working, but it's a huge benefit in that it's way more portable than Direct3D.

Comment: @RobertRouhani the lack of portability is only because DirectX is commercially only available from MS. There would be nothing technical preventing Khronos having included SDL/GLEW type functions with openGL

Comment: It's precisely because of this policy that OpenGL is used on everything from smart phones to supercomputers.

Comment: Just want to precise that OpenGL actually only expect vertex coordinates outputted by the vertex shader to be in clip-space. How you do that is up to you (eg: using matrices, voodoo, ...).

Answer (score 3):

Khronos removed these functions from the core profiles, but they are still available in the compatibility ones. 
The main reason is one of performance:

In most applications nowadays, the amount of information which must be passed back and forth between the renderer and the application is magnitude larger than ten years ago. So the ARB came up with the buffers (vertex arrays and vertex buffer objects) to maximize the use of the bandwidth available between the main system and the rendering hardware. However, if you start using the VBO mechanism to transfert data, then most of the legacy functions become useless.

That said, besides the need to support legacy applications, which is a sufficient reason for a compatibility profile, I think that this API is still useful for learning purpose.

As for your main question, the above is only valid for the full fledged version of OpenGL, not the ES one, which doesn't support the old primitives, and in this context an emulation layer is necessary.